# Proof of Darboux Theorem

Tags: differential-topology, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

I'm reading the proof of Darboux Theorem from Spivak's book on Mechanics.

After he gets a 1-form $\alpha$ and the form $\omega_t=\omega+t(\omega_1-\omega)$ he defines $X^t$ as a field with $X^t(0)=0$ and $i_{X^t}\omega_t=-\alpha$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Then he defines the 1-parameter family $f_t$ of diffeomorphisms generated by $X^t$. This is what I don't understand. Shouldn't every $X^t$ generate a whole 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms and not just one? Which diffeomorphism is $f_t$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that's going on is the vector field is varying as you're integrating it. We don't separately take integral curves for each. Instead we make different integral curves which follow the vector field $X^t$ at time $t$. Details:

*Compare: Time-independent*

A $1$-parameter family $f$ of diffeomorphisms generated by a single (i.e. time-independent) vector field $X$ comprises integral curves $\gamma$ satisfying $$\frac{d\gamma}{dt}(t) = X_{\gamma(t)}$$ That is, the derivative of $\gamma$ at $t$ equals the value of the vector field $X$ at the point $\gamma(t)$.

*Time-dependent*

When we allow the vector field to vary with time, so we have a smoothly varying family of vector fields with one for each $t$, called $X^t$, then we ask that the integral curves satisfy $$\frac{d\gamma}{dt}(t) = X^t_{\gamma(t)}$$ That is, the derivative of $\gamma$ at $t$ equals the value of the vector field $X^t$ at $\gamma(t)$.

---

In case it helps, in coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is the difference between having a vector field $V: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and solving $$\gamma'(t) = V(\gamma(t))$$ and having a time-dependent vector field $V: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and solving $$\gamma'(t) = V(t, \gamma(t))$$

Comment: I see... That makes a lot of sense. Spivak didn't explain it so much though. Can you recommend me some book or text on smooth manifolds where these fields are properly treated?

Comment: @G.Gallego I don't have it on hand at the moment but I suspect Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by Lee treats this.

Comment: @ G.Galego To follow-up: For Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by Lee it looks like there's a section called "Time-Dependent Vector Fields" in Chapter 9.

Answer (score 0):

$f_t$ is the diffeomorphism that takes a point $P$ to $U$, where $U$ is the point on the integral curve $\gamma$ of $X$ through $P$ with $\gamma(0) = P$ and $\gamma(t) = U$.

In words: $f_t$ is the result of flowing along $X$ for time $t$.

Comment: But $X^t$ depends on time itself too, so $f_t$ would just be $f_{0,t}$?

Comment: Ah... I see your point. Perhaps $f_t$ is the result of flowing along $X^t$ for one unit of time...or for $t$ units of time? Not at all clear. I'm leaving my (horribly incomplete) answer here in hopes it'll inspire someone who actually knows something to follow up. @TedShifrin?

Comment: You just solve $\dfrac d{dt} f_t(x) = X_t(f_t(x))$. Very non-autonomous ODE.